# Ruby on rails and UI Router not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, angular-ui-router

Alright... So I've installed UI Router and Rails-templates to handle AngujarJs in my project. So far everthing is fine. Except if a type the url manually into chrome's bar (e.g localhost:3000/sign_in) I get 'No routes matches for /sign_in' (Ruby error).

But if in my app I have a button for changing my state ($state.go) to that sign_in view, works just fine.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening there is that your angular app is intercepting the changes to the location bar for it's own purposes, and preventing the browser from making a http request to the new url, so all is well after the app has initialized.

When you reload the page the js app isn't loaded at first, so the browser sends the location in a new page load to the server. But because the server doesn't know about the angular app's routes, it tries to respond with it's own handler, which in this case doesn't exist.

The easiest way to fix this now is probably to change you ui-router config to include a # in the url.

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    ...snip
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

That should start including a # before the angular part of the route. The new path would be "/#/sign_in". The browser will know to send "/" before the # to the server, that would render the page with the angular init in int, then angular can handle the "/sign_in" part after the #.